# Handling contained exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I'm wondering how should one handle "contained" exceptions. Because the term isn't concrete enough, let me take an example of `PrivilegedActionException`.

In short, this exception will in its `cause` contain any checked exception thrown during the computation within `PrivilegedAction`.

Now if I have and method `computate() throws IOException` I'll - if executed on its own - handle it as:

```
try {
  computate();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
 // Handle file not found
} catch (SomeOtherSubtypeOfIOException ex) {
 // handle that again
}
```

Now as this has been executed in `PriviledgedAction` the only exception I get is `PrivilegedActionException`:

```
try {
  Subject.doAs(() -> computate());
} catch (PrivilegedActionException ex) {
  // Now what?
}
```

I can get the `IOException` from previous example by calling `ex.getCause()` but how would that look like? The obvious way looks odd ...

```
catch (PrivilegedActionException ex) {
  if (ex.getCause() instanceof FileNotFoundException.class) {
    // handle FileNotFound
  } else if (ex.getCause() instanceof xxx) {
    // something else
  }
}
```

Comment: This look pretty much the same but better explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437890/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-an-executionexception

Answer (score 0):

You could get the cause and re-throw it. Then handle exception with an outer try-catch.

```
catch (PrivilegedActionException ex) {
  Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
  if(cause !=null) throw ex.getCause();
  else ex.printStackTrace();
}
```