# Java ExecutorService invokeAll multiple task resolv

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, threadpool, java-threads

I am using executer service to run task in parallel . The parallel running method takes input integer and returns integer . As parallel task has return type , so I have used Callable anonymous class . You can see in below example `ExecutorServiceExample task(int i )` is called from executer . The task method also has waiting time for 1 second and throws exception for `i==7;`

In below implementation I am using invokeAll and using isDone and get trying to collect data .

The below program throws `IllegalMonitorStateException` .

What is wrong with Future task iteration and checking isDone and get() . How to handle exception of specific call . I want to run all 1 to 14 task in parallel and on all complete collect the return return type . Also in case of error what to know the input for which it thown exception like(7 and 14 )

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class MyException extends Exception{
    MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class ExecutorServiceExample {

    public int task(int i) throws MyException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Running task.."+i);
        wait(1000);
        if(i%7==0) {
            throw new MyException("multiple of 7 not allowed");
        }

        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14).stream().map(id->{
           return new Callable<Integer>() {
               @Override
               public Integer call() throws Exception {
                   ExecutorServiceExample executorServiceExample = new ExecutorServiceExample();
                   return executorServiceExample.task(id);
               }
           };
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        try{
            List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

            for (Future<Integer> task: results) {
                if(task.isDone()){
                    System.out.println(task.get());
                }
            }

        }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, every task produced an `IllegalMonitorStateException` because you did not call `wait` method in a `synchronized` block: [IllegalMonitorStateException on wait() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call). Maybe you should use `sleep` instead of `wait`.

`ExecutionException` is thrown by `future#get`. So if you narrow the scope of `try-catch`, 14 exceptions will actually be caught:

```
           for (Future<Integer> task: results) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(task.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you please explain  about isDone method , is it only true when task is computed and executed ? There could be chance that isDone is false i am putting sleep in each task execution .

Comment: In ExecutionException catch block I am able to get error message , but how to get information for input type the error is thrown .Like i=7 or 14

Comment: ```IsDone```: Returns true if this task completed. Completion may be due to normal termination, an exception, or cancellation -- in all of these cases, this method will return true.   You don't need to use ```isDone``` to determine whether the task is complete, ```get``` will block until the task execution is complete

Comment: And you should use ```if(i%7==0) ``` instead of ```if(i/7==0) ```

Comment: ohh yeah .. i%7 is correct . Thank you ``` IsDone ``` Returns true if this task completed. In my example why its returning true as its blocked for a second .  IsDone checks what task completion .

Comment: No need to use ```isDone```, because you already use ```executorService#invokeAll```.  ```InvokeAll ``` blocks until all tasks are complete.

Comment: Is there any way to know for which input error is thrown. Is there any better way to do error handling

Comment: Now that you have defined your own exception class, maybe you can pass the wrong input to your exception class, and get it in catch block, for example: ```Throwable cause = e.getCause(); if (cause instanceof MyException) {
                            System.out.println(((MyException) cause).getErrorInput());
                        }```. You can refer to other similar questions
: [what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-an-executionexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437890/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-an-executionexception)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you designed it like this. But obviously, it has many problems.
`i/7==0 or i % 7 ==0`?  `examples` aren't locks, so why use wait? the futures that the returns of 'invokeAll' are must be done but maybe get an exception when invoke get.
Is this what you want?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class MyException extends Exception {
    MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class ExecutorServiceExample {

    public int task(int i) throws MyException, InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            throw new MyException("multiple of 7 not allowed");
        }

        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
                .map(id -> (Callable<Integer>) () -> {
                    ExecutorServiceExample executorServiceExample = new ExecutorServiceExample();
                    return executorServiceExample.task(id);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        executorService.shutdown();
        for (Future<Integer> task : results) {
            try {
                System.out.println(task.get());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```